# VS Code Open Custom Files

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a text file which has metadata on each line.

```
<MetaData><CodePart><MetaData>
<MetaData><CodePart><MetaData>
<MetaData><CodePart><MetaData>
<MetaData><CodePart><MetaData>
<MetaData><CodePart><MetaData>
<MetaData><CodePart><MetaData>
```

I am trying to create an extension in VS Code which can open the file in the VS Code editor by removing the `<MetaData>` from the file and just displaying the `<CodePart>`.

I was able to achieve that in Visual Studio by handling the way the file opens and instead of opening the main file, I would open a temporary file which has just the `<CodePart>`

I am fairly new to the VS Code Extensibility model. Can you please suggest any API which can be used to open a temporary file instead of the main file while opening.

Answer (score 0):

That's a typical use case for [custom text editors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors#custom-text-editor). VS Code manages the text model, and you provide a UI that shows whatever you want, using a webview. There is an [example for a custom text editor](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/custom-editor-sample/src/catScratchEditor.ts) that shows how easy it is to set this up.

Comment: I understand that and with that I will lose on the LSP features. I was thinking if there was a way with which I could fool vs code to open open some other file.